# bootstrap 4 mix collapsable and non collapseable nav elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap nav bar, and I would like to have both collapse-able and non collapse-able menu items.

my code is as follows:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://ngohub.asia">
      <%= image_tag 'ngohublogo.png', class: 'hidden-md-down img-responsive', style: 'width: 100%'%>
        <%= image_tag 'ngohublogo.png', class: 'hidden-lg-up img-responsive w-100'%>
    </a>
    <div class="w-100" style="float:right;">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link">|</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The login and sign up links appear as expected to the left of the brand, 
however when I decrese the size of the browser window to simulate a mobile device, the links aren't sharing space with the brand as I would like:

[image: non collapsed]

Here it is on a full width screen

[image: messed up spacing]

here it is in a simulated mobile view. I would like login and sign up to be next to the brand and next to the hamburger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing of note, [visibility helpers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) have been renamed in the latest version of bootstrap. `hidden-md` has been replaced with `.d-md-none`, etc.

Second, I made sure to declare `flex-direction: row;` on `.navbar-nav` to arrange it's children horizontally instead of vertically.

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav{
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://ngohub.asia">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x50" class="hidden-md-down img-responsive" style="width: 100%" />
    </a>
    <div style="float:right;">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link">|</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways you can approach this. Remember that in Bootstrap 4.1, the `navbar-toggleable` classes have been replaced with `navbar-expand-`.

Use `flex-row` on the first navbar-nav so that it doens't wrap/stack in a column on smaller screens. Use `flex-grow-1` on the collapse so that it expands the remaining width.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/LBY9LXio09

```
<nav class="navbar clg navbar-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://ngohub.asia">
            <img src="//placehold.it/40?text=sm" class="d-lg-none d-inline">
            <img src="//placehold.it/100x30?text=lg" class="d-lg-inline d-none">
        </a>
        <div class="mr-auto flex-shrink-1">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-1">
                    <a class="nav-link">|</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline d-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```